# Inverse Laplace transform of functions with jump discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform

Given a function $F(s)$, suppose we define its inverse Laplace transform as:

\begin{equation}
f(t) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\left(\frac{k}{t}\right)^{k+1}F^{(k)}\left( \frac{k}{t} \right)
\end{equation}

for $t > 0$.

Now suppose we take the ordinary Laplace transform of a function with a jump discontinuity. In this case, what would the above formula recover when applied to the Laplace transform of the function at the jump discontinuity? Would it be $\frac{1}{2}(f(x^+) + f(x^-))$?

Comment: If you take a unit step function at $x=1$, you get $F(s)=e^{-s}/s$, and using the inversion formula I think you get $f(1)=0$.

Comment: Isn't the Heaviside function continuous at $x = 1$?

Comment: No, but it doesn't matter what is is defined as at $x=1$ because the transform $F(s)$ is the same.